# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Awall_Helper_Versions' not found in public_html/***********/app/Mage.php on line 547

Tags: magento

While adding return product request i got this Fatal error:

> Class 'Mage_Awall_Helper_Versions' not found in public_html/***********/app/Mage.php on line 547

```
public static function helper($name)
{
    $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
        self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
    }
```

Comment: I can't see a question...

Comment: Have you clean cache and disable compiler ?

Answer (score 0):

Search helper function in you code. Please check in config.xml file for your "Versions" helper.

```
<helpers>
      <versions>
         <class>Awall_Versions_Helper</class>
      </versions>
</helpers>
```

call your helper using `Mage::helper('versions')`

Answer (score 0):

This problem generally comes when Magento doesn't find the mentioned helper class defined in config.xml file of the module, to resolve this problem you need to

1) Find the module named "Awall" either in community or in local code pool, then
2) Check whether you have helper class defined properly or not (if not correct it)